# Detecting if type implements ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I am trying to check if a type implements the generic ICollection<T> interface, since this is a base interface for any of my generic collections.

The below code doesn't work

```
GetType(ICollection(Of)).IsAssignableFrom(
    objValue.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

What's a good way of detecting if a type implements a generic interface?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
CustomCollection c = new CustomCollection();

bool implementICollection = c.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                            .Any(x => x.IsGenericType &&
                            x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; I've tested it

Comment: perhaps also consider GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableTo(typeof(ICollection<>)) to get derived collection types, e.g. List etc.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the others is the following:

```
if (MyObject is ICollection<T>)
  ...
```

Note: This will only work if `T` is known at compile time.